# How to export Azure Kubernetes logs to Storage account or view old pod logs from Applications insights?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-application-insights, azure-aks, azure-monitoring

In AKS, how to view a deleted pod logs for tracing purposes? Incase of failed logs too would like to store or export the logs.

I have application insights enabled but only the logs of pods currently running can be viewed from there.

I am looking for something like exporting every pod log to a storage account

Answer (score 0):

If this current configured Application Insights resource is a **workspace-based** resource already, you can use [diagnostic settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry#diagnostic-settings-based-export) for exporting telemetry.

Select `Diagnostic settings > add diagnostic setting` from within your Application Insights resource. You can select all tables, or a subset of tables to archive to a storage account, or to stream to an Azure Event Hub as convenient.

However, if it is a **classic** Application Insights resource, you can export telemetry by creating a [Continuous Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry). However, note that Continuous export has been **deprecated** and it is recommended to [migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource) to a workspace-based Application Insights resource to use diagnostic settings.